# Linux NASM - rewriting character stored in .data segment - segfault

Tags: linux, assembly, segmentation-fault, nasm

probably a very beginner's question, but I'm really interested in how to make it work.

I have following assembly code (heavily inspired from [here](http://www.safemode.org/files/zillion/shellcode/doc/Writing_shellcode.html), the rename() example):

```
[SECTION .text]
global _start

_start:
    mov             esi, msg        ; saves pointer to string to ESI
    xor             eax, eax
    mov byte        [esi+6], al     ; terminates first string with NULL char
    mov byte        [esi+13], al    ; terminates second string with NULL char
    mov byte        al, 38          ; syscall number (38 = rename)
    lea             ebx, [esi]      ; put the adress of /tmp/a in EBX
    lea             ecx, [esi+7]    ; put the adress of /tmp/b in ECX
    int             0x80            ; syscall execution

    mov             al, 0x01        ; prepare to exit!
    xor             ebx, ebx
    int             0x80            ; exit!

[SECTION .data]
msg:            db '/tmp/a#/tmp/b#'
```

Let me explain it: This program calls syscall `rename` to rename file `/tmp/a` to `/tmp/b` The string in section .data contains name of the source file and name of the target file.

Because I want to avoid NULLs, I decided to put # instead of NULLs and change it on runtime. However, the program terminates with SEGFAULT. It really seems that there is a problem with rewriting the # character(s) in .data segment. My question is - how should I deal with it and make it work? I know it's a beginner question, maybe I'm missing something very important.

Thanks for any advice.

### EDIT - commands used for assembling and linking

This is for NASM:

```
nasm -f elf -o ThisWorks.o ThisWorks.asm
```

And this for linker (notice that I'm building it as 32bit, although I have 64bit Phenom II).

```
ld -melf_i386 -o ThisWorks.aout ThisWorks.o
```

Than I execute it:

```
./ThisWorks.aout
```

And the result is:

```
Segmentation fault
```

### Disassembly

This is disassembly by `objdump -D ThisWorks.aout`

```
ThisWorks.aout:     file format elf32-i386


Disassembly of section .text:

08048080 <_start>:
 8048080:   be 9c 90 04 08          mov    $0x804909c,%esi
 8048085:   31 c0                   xor    %eax,%eax
 8048087:   88 46 06                mov    %al,0x6(%esi)
 804808a:   88 46 0d                mov    %al,0xd(%esi)
 804808d:   b0 26                   mov    $0x26,%al
 804808f:   8d 1e                   lea    (%esi),%ebx
 8048091:   8d 4e 07                lea    0x7(%esi),%ecx
 8048094:   cd 80                   int    $0x80
 8048096:   b0 01                   mov    $0x1,%al
 8048098:   31 db                   xor    %ebx,%ebx
 804809a:   cd 80                   int    $0x80

Disassembly of section .data:

0804909c <msg>:
 804909c:   2f                      das    
 804909d:   74 6d                   je     804910c <_end+0x60>
 804909f:   70 2f                   jo     80490d0 <_end+0x24>
 80490a1:   61                      popa   
 80490a2:   23 2f                   and    (%edi),%ebp
 80490a4:   74 6d                   je     8049113 <_end+0x67>
 80490a6:   70 2f                   jo     80490d7 <_end+0x2b>
 80490a8:   62 23                   bound  %esp,(%ebx)
```

### SOLUTION

The debugging has shown, that program works normally, but falls into segfault when there is no file to rename. Otherwise my code works as expected. Sorry for that.

Comment: Have you tried running it with `gdb`, to see which instruction causes the segfault?

Comment: Hit my head with something. Debuggin showed, that the segfault happens at the end of the program and after small research I revealed, that the file /tmp/a was missing, which caused SEGFAULT. It means, that the assembly code is alright. Sorry for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Running your probram under strace show:

```
execve("./a.out", ["./a.out"], [/* 67 vars */]) = 0
[ Process PID=7054 runs in 32 bit mode. ]
rename("/tmp/a", "/tmp/b")              = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
syscall_4294967041(0, 0x80490a3, 0, 0x804909c, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0) = -1 (errno 38)
--- SIGSEGV (Segmentation fault) @ 0 (0) ---
+++ killed by SIGSEGV +++
Segmentation fault
```

Conclusions:

1. Your problem has nothing to do with rewriting the `.data` section -- the rename syscall is executed as you would expect.
2. Your setup for `exit` is incorrect.

   To fix it, change `mov al, 0x01` to `mov eax, 0x01`.

Comment: Well spotted! If rename returns 0 in `eax` the bug goes unnoticed and the code will work, while when it returns -1 in `eax` because the file does not exist, only setting `al` will cause `eax` to contain `0xFFFFFF01` which is `4294967041`, the syscall number in the strace output.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are writing shellcode: You cannot access anything in the `.data` segment from your shellcode, because your shellcode will execute in the process of the exploited piece of software and there will be no data segment there (or more precisely, there is only the data segment of the exploited process). Shellcode has no segmented structure, it is generally just a linear buffer of bytes. In any case, you will have to tuck your data onto the end of your shellcode.

Comment: Yes, it's a preparation for understanding shellcodes. However, I would first like to understand how assembly code executes standalone and therefore I'm curious about how to repair my code to be working.

Comment: Can you show us how you assemble and execute your code?